# Find us on facebook - link to a facebook page from a web site

Tags: facebook, web

I want to include on my web site a 'Find us on Facebook' graphic and link it to a facebook 'business' page - nothing more sophisticated than that. Do I simply copy the graphic from another random web site and put in my link, or is there a better 'facebook approved' way of doing this? (I've tried it the non-facebook way already and its necessary for users who click the link to log in to facebook. Can anyone also advise of the privacy settings that will avoid this)? Thanks

Comment: Unless I'm confused, I think you should just make a facebook graphic, or find a free one online and wrap it in a link: `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/cocacola">your image</a>`  If they are already logged into facebook, they will be still after clicking the link.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considerd making use of the Like Box social plugin? See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin mentioned by nav is definitely the way to go. By using the facebook plugin, users won't have to login (granted they're already logged in to Facebook). This is because the plugin can access the cookie set by Facebook whenever they logged in. Your ad-hoc link cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.facebook.com/badges/page.php  This is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the fact that you can use a simple image and a link to the page.

However the answer provided by NAV would be the most 'facebook approved' way.